# Python Programming Issue

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a python program that allows a user to input as many positive integers as they want.  When the user inputs a positive or negative integer, the program generates a list of the inputted numbers that is sorted and also generates an average of the list inputted by the user.
Someone please help.  I need to know this by this evening.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: We don't do homework. Please show us what code you have so far.

Comment: We're not here to do your homework, this is a site for concrete programming questions. Giving a list of requirements and expecting someone to spoon feed you is not how you are going to learn how to write code. Please take some time to read http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: This is doable in 4 lines of trivial code. Try to measure the urgency of your tone, and do some legwork of your own. Or at least make an appearance of doing so.

Comment: "Need Help Fast" is rude - you are asking for help and telling people to hurry up already?

Comment: If you want to know it by this evening, try reading a short tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

We don't do your homework here, but without divulging a complete solution, think about writing a loop to query the user for integers and add them to a Python list. You can make use of the `sorted()` and `sort()` functions in Python to sort your data. Averaging values in a list is trivial and can be easily found online or with basic programming knowledge (sum the values in the list and divide that total by the length of the list). Also beware of integer division depending on your version of Python.